# Unity PHOTON/PUN Collision Detection

Tags: unity, collision-detection

I am trying to create a virtual 3D chat room based on character interaction (just like in Sims2), so I have added a collider on the "user's in-game character". The problem is that when I enable the box collider, the character movement looks like it's freaking out (the character is seen as if it is moving fast from left to right & the movement is not smooth).

When I remove the box collider, the player moves smooth and no other fake-movement can be seen. What is the problem??

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you have attatched a rigidbody to your character it's likely that the collider is colliding with something in an unusual way(maybe it's stuck inside the floor) and the rigidbody spazzes out.
Check if there are any other colliders next to your character's collider.
Other than that, it may be a script issue. Check your OnCollision functions.

Comment: I have attached a rigidbody to the character, and the collider does not hit other colliders like the ground, other characters collider. Does the collider need to be placed into the "Observed Components" ?

Answer (score 0):

Property replication (which is what Photon does) and physics don't go well together. For first-person shooters, this is okay because all physics needs to be used for is keeping the player from going through walls and some local raycast detection. Complex physics where objects simulated on multiple computers are hitting and bouncing off each other leads to freaky behaviors. Since game states are different, one player sends off a position that isn't consistent with the object on other players' machines.

One solution is to just ditch the physics engine because it tries too hard to keep objects from overlapping. Instead, implement your own system where objects are slowly seperated if they overlap. This will remove the jitter and make snapping positions more acceptable. Alternatively, you could just take out collision between networked objects completely.

By the way, have you tested your game offline? It's possible that your movement scripts are just broken and this is unrelated to networking.